# AutoHotkey script for search engine by keyword in Firefox

Tags: firefox, search-engine, autohotkey

I am trying to use AutoHotkey (v1.1.15.02) to automatically use one of my search engines in Firefox (31.0).

I thought the best way to call the search engine is to use my predefined key words. Usually, if I type "d awesome", Firefox will open "http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/awesome" for me. 
Now I just want to get the same behaviour when I call Firefox from AutoHotkey. I thought it should work with this code:

```
#ä::
send ^c
IfWinExist, ahk_class MozillaWindowClass
{   WinActivate
Send ^t{Space}
SetKeyDelay 100,100
sleep 500
Send d ^v{Enter}
} 
else 
{
Run firefox
sleep 2500
Send {F6}d ^v{Enter} 
}
return
```

It does almost everything it should, except firefox keeps using google to search "d awesome" instead of calling my predefined search engine. Any ideas on how Firefox can recognize the key?

Comment: 1) Does you script never work or only if firefox isn't already open? 2) Why are you sending `CTRL+T+SPACE`? 3) Have you tried sending the clipboard contents rather than pasting it? (`Send, ^td %ClipBoard%{ENTER}`)

Comment: @MCL, thanks a lot for your comment! Indeed, the extra {Space} which was an artefact I forgot has caused the problem. After removing it, both ways work actually! Thanks for your help! It seems that the issue was a lot smaller than I thought...

Comment: Great! Please post your solutions as an answer and accept it, so that others know your problem's solved.

Comment: Please post the solution as a answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I realized what I was trying to do is a lot faster if I just call the search directly as an URL in firefox. I'm posting my solution in the hope that other autohotkey users may find it beneficial:

```
#^e::
send ^c
Clipwait
sleep 200
Run C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe "http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/%ClipBoard%"
return
```

It is important for performance to call firefox with the full path!